# Is it possible to change the name of extbase parameters

Tags: typo3, extbase

I name all my extensions like MyCompanyExtensionName. Now my customer is not happy with my Companyname in the extbase parameters on his website eg. "tx_MyCompanyExtensionName_pi1[action]". Is it possible to change only the name of the paramters without renaming all extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the extension [realurl](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl), which allows you to create human readable URLs for the extension. Depending on the configuration, you could completely remove the parameter name from the URL (identifying the parameter by its position), or add an arbitrary alias.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to identify a parameter by its position, please?

Comment: @xandi: [Here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/realurl/1.12.8/Realurl/Configuration/UrlEnDecodingBackground/Index.html) is an explanation. The parameters that are identified by position are called "preVars" and "fixedPostVars", where pre and post refer to the position in before or after the page path.